# Slow view switch using UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, block

I'm working on my first app that integrates with a web service. Right now I have two views with their respective view controllers. I have a login view, which is where users will login to the app and I will verify and store there login credentials and I have a main view which shows all the users info from the web service. My two views work correctly individually however after verifying the credentials of the user on my login view I want to switch views to my login view. To do this I'm using UIViewController. Here is my code for when the login button is pressed:

```
-(IBAction)logIn:(id)sender{

    //Show network activity is happening
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    application.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    //Validate credentials
    [_loginNetworkingContorller checkCredentialsWithUsername:self.username.text withPassword:self.password.text completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if(!error){

            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;

            if (httpResp.statusCode == 200) {
                //if we get back a successful status code save username and password in keychain.
                NSLog(@"SUCESS");
                NSDictionary *credentials = @{self.username.text: self.password.text};
                [KeychainUserPass save:@"INSERT APP NAME HERE" data:credentials];
                NSLog(@"go to new page");

                //print response from webservice for debugging purposes
                NSMutableDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@", jsonObject);

                //switch to new view controller
                UIViewController *mainController = [[RDMainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RDMainViewController" bundle:nil];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainController animated:NO];
            }
            else{
                //Error case, handle it.
                NSLog(@"ERROR");
            }
        }
        else{
            //Error case, handle it.
            NSLog(@"ERROR");
        }
    }];
}
```

And here `checkCredentialsWithUsername` method:

```
-(void)checkCredentialsWithUsername:(NSString *)username withPassword:(NSString *)password completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))myCompletion
{
    //Create request URL
    NSString *requestString = @"WEB_SERVICE_URL";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Store password and user name for authentication
    NSData *userPasswordData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", username, password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64EncodedCredential = [userPasswordData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSString *authString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", base64EncodedCredential];

    //Create an NSURL session
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig=[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    sessionConfig.HTTPAdditionalHeaders=@{@"Authorization":authString};

    self.session=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        myCompletion(data, response, error);
    }];

    [dataTask resume];
}
```

My issue is that it's taking an incredibly long time to switch views. Like sometimes over a minute. At first I thought it was the network connection but then I printed the data I was receiving from the web service and it was appearing very quickly. Even after I printed the data it was still taking a very long time for views to switch. I'm not really sure why but I think it has to do with the way I'm doing my blocks. Any idea why it's taking me such a long time to switch views?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to do the view controller switch in the main thread. [NSOpertionQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{}];

Answer (score 0):

@Danyun was right. I needed to do the following:

```
           if (httpResp.statusCode == 200) {
                //if we get back a successful status code save username and password in keychain.
                NSLog(@"SUCESS");
                NSDictionary *credentials = @{self.username.text: self.password.text};
                [KeychainUserPass save:@"INSERT APP NAME HERE" data:credentials];
                NSLog(@"go to new page");

                //print response from webservice for debugging purposes
                NSMutableDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@", jsonObject);

                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    //test to make sure we are on the main Queue for UI update

                    //switch to the new view controller
                    UIViewController *mainController = [[RDMainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RDMainViewController" bundle:nil];
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainController animated:NO];
                }];
            }
```